# Why isn't my TikZ line straight?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This tikz picture code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (0, 1);
        \node at (a) {\textbullet};
        \node[above left] at (a) {$\mathbf{a}$};

        \coordinate (b) at (5, 5);
        \node at (b) {\textbullet};
        \node[above right] at (b) {$\mathbf{b}$};

        \draw (a) -- (b);

        \coordinate (c) at (-1, 0);
        \node at (c) {\textbullet};
        \node[above left] at (c) {$\mathbf{c}$};
        \draw[dashed] (c) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

Why don't the two lines lie on top of each other (is floating-point error to blame?), and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Why should they overlap? AB has a slope of 4/5, CB of 5/6, and AC of 1/1. The three points do not lie on one straight line, don't they?

Comment: Your line is perfectly straight! The line between `c` and `b` is `y=5/6(x+1)`. So the point `(0,5/6)` is on this line but `a=(0,1)` is not!

Comment: I am thinking, that this question should be closed because the underlying problem is not LaTeX(TikZ) related, and the problem does not have any general interest for future readers.

Comment: Wow, am I dumb. Thanks everyone. Let's pretend this never happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in above comments, you problem is not related to `TikZ` but to geometry (of course if I understand your question correctly). Proof: see code below and obtained result.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-1.5,-0.5) grid (5.5,5.5);
        \coordinate (a) at (0, 1);
        \node at (a) {\textbullet};
        \node[above left] at (a) {$\mathbf{a}$};

        \coordinate (b) at (5, 5);
        \node at (b) {\textbullet};
        \node[above right] at (b) {$\mathbf{b}$};

        \draw (a) -- (b);

        \coordinate (c) at (-1, 0);
        \node at (c) {\textbullet};
        \node[below right] at (c) {$\mathbf{c}$};
        \draw[dashed] (c) -- (b);
% the right position for coordinate c, 
% that it to be lying on strait through b and c is (-5/4,0)
        \coordinate (d) at (-5/4, 0);
        \node at (d) {\textbullet};
        \node[below left] at (d) {$\mathbf{c'}$};
    \scoped[on background layer]
        \draw[dashed,red!30, ultra thick] (d) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]